# MySQL Workbench removes previously defined triggers for the table

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench, alter-table

I am using

> MySQL Workbench CE for Windows version 5.2.47  revision 10398

and

> MySQL Version 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.10.1

My problem is that when I add a new (different) trigger on my table all of my previously defined triggers are dropped.

Or to be more specific:
I have a table with an AFTER_DELETE trigger defined: `Test_table_ADEL`.

When I add an AFTER_INSERT trigger `Test_table_AINS` on the same table and click "Apply", the Workbench decides to drop all the previously defined triggers.

`DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS DB.Test_table_ADEL`

I am able to manually change the SQL statements before they get executed and I can remove the DROP for that trigger but still it is a very annoying behavior.

Does anybody have any ideas of what might be causing this?
I can recall a few months earlier that I had multiple triggers defined per table with no problems adding AFTER_INSERT, AFTER_UPDATE, BEFORE_DELETE triggers and not losing the old ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest MySQL Workbench version (6.0 GA at the moment and 6.1 in beta). This is a bug that is fixed in a newer version already.

Comment: I upgraded from 5.2.47 (with trigger problems) to 6.1.4, and I can confirm that the problem is solved.